# How to override JavaScript's Date object?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create my own localized version of Date object. I know there's a method called `toLocaleDateString()` which has a locale parameter for example in order to display date with Arabic calendar we just need to set locale argument:

```
.toLocaleDateString('ar-EG')
```

Now my question is that How can I override this behavior to display my own calendar with its locale format?

Comment: 1. __Don't__ override the `Date` object.

Comment: 2. Is your question about changing the behavior of `Date` methods or rendering a calendar?

Comment: @Mathletics Rendering my customized calendar.

Answer (score 3):

See if this example helps . First I saved the default function in a custom method . Then override the default method making dealings. Look:

```js
Date.prototype.toLocaleDateStringDefault = Date.prototype.toLocaleDateString;

Date.prototype.toLocaleDateString = function(){
    var options = {year: "numeric", month: "long", day: "numeric"};
    var result = this.toLocaleDateStringDefault("pr-BR", options);
    return result;
}

document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].innerHTML = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to see, didn't think of saving the original method from the prototype

Answer (score 2):

It is considered very bad practice to override a native method like this, but since you asked:

```
Date.prototype.toLocaleDateString = function () {
   // Your custom function
}
var foo = new Date();
foo.toLocaleDateString();
```

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript we are using prototypes, so to override this method you have to do next:

```
Date.prototype.toLocaleDateString = // and your method
```

I hope it will help you